# Automating dropping the columns with variance = 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a dataframe which has 377 columns, how do I automate (using a for loop probably) to check the nunique() of the columns and if it is equal to 1 which means the variance = 0, I want to drop that column. Please help me, highly grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `nunqiue`

```
out = df.loc[:,df.nunique()!=1]
```